# Is it possible to regenerate my private key (SSL)?

Tags: tls

I've managed to lose my private.key file for my SSL certificate. Is it at all possible to create a new one if I know the passkey and CSR info?

If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "passkey" is just for encryption of the private key, but it is chosen independently of the private key. Correspondingly, no information about the private key can be obtained from the passkey (the passkey is useful information to unlock the private key *file*, but you do not have that file).

The certificate request contains only the public key; by construction, the private key cannot be (in practice) rebuilt from the public key (which is why the public key can be made, in fact, public).

So the answer is: no, your private key is lost. *If* the private key could be recomputed from what you have left, then it would be cause for concern. You will have to generate a new private key, and obtain a new certificate.

Comment: oh okay, I suppose I'll have to get it reissued then :(

Comment: Some vendors allow you to "re-key" a certificate. Essentially they sign a completely new certificate for you, but at lower cost to you and with the original expiration date.

Comment: yeah my vendor does it for free, just found out :)

Comment: @Seb what vendor is that?